# Derivative of mixed matrix terms with inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've been trying to solve two matrix derivative terms including an inverse matrix but I am unable to find a clue :

1) Derivative of $KG^{-1}J$ with respect to $G$.

2) Derivative of $J^{T}G^{-T}KG^{-1}J$ with respect to $G$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried, and why you are having difficulty with the problem, and I'm sure someone will be happy to help you!

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the answer of user7530 in the equivalent way. If $f(G)=KG^{-1}J$, then the derivative is the linear function $Df_G:H\rightarrow -KG^{-1}HG^{-1}J$ where $H$ is a square matrix. For 2., if $g(G)=J^T{G^{-1}}^TKG^{-1}J$, then we derive a product: $Dg_G:H\rightarrow -J^T(G^{-1}HG^{-1})^TKG^{-1}J-J^T{G^{-1}}^TKG^{-1}HG^{-1}J$. If $K$ is a symmetric matrix then the derivative is $-U-U^T$ where $U=J^T{G^{-1}}^TKG^{-1}HG^{-1}J$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $GG^{-1} = I$, and matrix multiplication is linear,
$$0 = \frac{dG}{dx}G^{-1} + G\frac{dG^{-1}}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dG^{-1}}{dx} = -G^{-1}\frac{dG}{dx}G^{-1}.$$

Then e.g.
$$\frac{dKG^{-1}J}{dg_{ij}} = -KG^{-1}\delta_{ij}G^{-1}J$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the matrix with a 1 as its $(i,j)$th entry and zero elsewhere.